# How to trigger primeng colorpicker using a button?

Tags: angular, angular6, primeng, color-picker

Here is stackblitz link:- 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtv8vo?file=src/app/app.component.html

Here, colorpicker is not opening while click of a button? How to open color pallete onclick of button?

```
<p-colorPicker [(ngModel)]="color"></p-colorPicker>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Add COlor</button>
```

Comment: Do you want to open the p-colorPicker by clicking the button instead of the p-colorPicker?

Comment: Yes and populate color at its place as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way:

```
<p-colorPicker #pcp [(ngModel)]="color"></p-colorPicker>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="pcp.onInputClick()">Add Color</button>
```

Comment: +1 This is the simplest way to do this. We cannot simply just call pcp.click() here since it's a custom component and they handle clicks through their own function onInputClick. It's easiest to just check their components source code for further knowledge of how it works [source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/colorpicker/colorpicker.ts)

Comment: Thanks, for simplest solution. Can you please help how to change default color ie red to some another color.

Comment: Let try :) @ViewChild('pcp') pcp: ColorPicker;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.pcp.defaultColor = '#ffffff';
  }

Comment: Not working this example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtv8vo
Can you please help me share a fresh link? @phucnh

Answer (score 2):

Use ViewChild and call on them `onInputClick()`.

In AppComponent add @ViewChild and import ColorPicker component.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ColorPicker} from 'primeng/colorpicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('colorpicker') colorpicker: ColorPicker;
  name = 'Angular';
  color:any;

  clickButton(): void {
    this.colorpicker.onInputClick()
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<p-colorPicker #colorpicker [(ngModel)]="color"></p-colorPicker>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="clickButton()">Add COlor</button>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwvivn)

Comment: The colorpallete is not opening on the click of button.